# calculate days difference between two days in hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to display the records where difference in days between "empdate" column and current date is lesser than equal to 365.

[image]

The column empdate is of varchar datatype.I have written the below query but not able to achieve the result. Where i am getting all the records which are greater than 365 between the current date and empdate.
Can anybody please help me on this.

```
select * from table where 
cast(datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yy-MM-dd'),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(empdate as string)'yyMMdd'),'yy-MM-dd') as int)<=365;
```

Comment: Please update that first paragraph of text, because I don't know what you're describing. It looks like you're missing one (or more) words.

Comment: @Mike Pomax' Kamermans I have updated context in the first paragraph. Please let me know if you need more inputs

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan, added the answer please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below query might be helpful to you,

```
select datediff(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date),'yyyy-MM-dd')),
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(empdate, 'yyMMdd')))) <=365 as daydiff 
from time_table;
```

**Test for the query from hive:**

```
create table if not exists time_table(empdate string, empvalue string) row format
 delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

insert into table time_table values ('101001','A'),('200101','B'),
('100619','C'),('110707','D');

hive> select *, datediff(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date),'yyyy-MM-dd')),
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(empdate, 'yyMMdd')))) <=365 as daydiff 
from time_table;

OK
101001  A       false
200101  B       true
100619  C       false
110707  D       false
```